# Error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a Flask App that utilizes SQLAlchemy for database operations.  During manual database initialization -- when running flask --app swimtracker init-db from the commandi line -- receive this error (Error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a read only database).  This occurs after the database is initialized and tables are created and at the commit of the first data (a list of dictionaries).  Specifically the error occurs on db_session.commit() in the db_list_dictionary_write function though based on testing I believe this code is appropriate and it's identifying an issue somewhere else.

The application is divided among a number of modules.   An application is created in an app factory in **init.py**

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    # This is an app factory to allow for multiple applications for testing
    # Creates Flask application with config to instance by default
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    
    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path, exist_ok=True)
    except OSError:
        pass
        
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE='sqlite:///' + os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'swimmer.db'),
    )
    
    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # import swimtracker views and database to initialize for use in app
    from . import auth, database, main, posts
    
    # Create the engine and database app engine configuration and 
    app.config['engine'] = create_engine(app.config['DATABASE'], echo=True)
    
    # with ensures app context popped and cleanup code executed.
    with app.app_context():
        # creates database session and makes available "globally"
        db_session = database.init_db(app)
        app.config['db_session'] = db_session

    # Teardown session at end
    @app.teardown_appcontext
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        if db_session is not None:
            db_session.close()
        
    return app
```

Here is relevant code in database.py where the init_db resides as well as the function where the commit identifies the Read Only issue (db_list_dictionary_write)

```
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
db_session = scoped_session(Session)

def init_db(app):
    
    # allow init-db CLI to run Flask app
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)

    # configure engine and bind to a session.
    # Adjust Session configuration for engine configurations (principaly the
    # location of the DATABASE)
    engine = app.config['engine']
    Session.configure(bind=engine)
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import swimtracker.models
    
    # Set query property for Base class and bind Base to models.
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    # Base.query = db_session.query_property()
    return db_session



@click.command('init-db')
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    # Call creat_app to load app
    app = create_app()

    # obtain path to swimmer.db in instance folder    
    db_path = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'swimmer.db')
    # Read in Cl2 Data
    cl2_path = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'Good.cl2')
    swims = cl2_read_process(cl2_path, False)

    # If existing db exists, delete and replace by re-loading app
    print(f'initDB-Command-session: {db_session}')
    if os.path.exists(db_path):
        if db_session != None:
            db_session.close()
        try:
            os.remove(db_path)
            app = create_app()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            print(f"Error: {e.strerror}")
    
    # Call database initializer within the context of the app
    with app.app_context():
        # init_db(app)
        db_list_dictionary_write(swims)
                          
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')
    
    return app
```

```
def db_list_dictionary_write(data):
    from swimtracker.models import Data
    data_obj = [Data(**data_dict) for data_dict in data]
    db_session.add_all(data_obj)
    try:
        db_session.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db_session.rollback()
        print(f'Error: {str(e)}')
        traceback.print_exc()
    return
```

I am a novice programmer but have spent hours trouble shooting and researching (stack overflow discussions, AI helpers, trial and error, etc) and haven't identified the source of the issue.  I also have written a test suite that doesn't identify the error though this might be because of poor design.

I have confirmed that my linux user profile has read / write access to the swimmer.db file and instance directory.  I also believe...but am not certain...that my use of os instance_path has meant that the DB is consistently in the same location throughout the program.

Here is the broader traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2112, in _exec_insertmany_context
dialect.do_execute(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 922, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/swimtracker/database.py", line 86, in db_list_dictionary_write
db_session.commit()
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 597, in commit
return self._proxied.commit()
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1967, in commit
trans.commit(_to_root=True)
File "<string>", line 2, in commit
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1256, in commit
self._prepare_impl()
File "<string>", line 2, in _prepare_impl
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1231, in _prepare_impl
self.session.flush()
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4310, in flush
self._flush(objects)
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4445, in _flush
with util.safe_reraise():
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4406, in _flush
flush_context.execute()
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 466, in execute
rec.execute(self)
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 642, in execute
util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 93, in save_obj
_emit_insert_statements(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1136, in _emit_insert_statements
result = connection.execute(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1416, in execute
return meth(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement
ret = self._execute_context(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1843, in _execute_context
return self._exec_insertmany_context(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2120, in _exec_insertmany_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2343, in _handle_dbapi_exception
raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2112, in _exec_insertmany_context
dialect.do_execute(
File "/home/jstaadek/cs50g/x/2023/week/Final/swimtracker/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 922, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database
[SQL: INSERT INTO data_table (lname, fname, mname, smid, dob, swimage, swimgender, gender, distance, strokeid, eventid, eventage, swimdate, swimtime, length, exhibition, swimplace, swimpoints, teamsymbol, teamname, meetname, swimpool) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING id]
[parameters: ('Jordan', 'Michael', '', '051297MIC*JO', '1997-05-12', '15', 'M', 'M', 50, 1, '9', '1518', '2012-06-16', '00:30.43', 'S', '', '', '', 'CP', 'Crestorn Road Swim Team', 'CP 2012 Time Trials', 'Crestorn Road')]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Comment: Did you print out the path of the db to make sure it is what you think it is and not creating some duplicate in some weird place?  You can also use `test -w db_path.db` to test write access on linux.